# Insomnia : generated code doesn't return the same result as insomnia

Tags: curl, request, wget, insomnia

The issue happens when searching on https://forum.mobilism.org

An account is needed, so I created one and then created a request in insomnia to login on this url : https://forum.mobilism.org/ucp.php?mode=login

The cookies are then stored by insomnia, and I created a request to search with a keyword on this url : https://forum.mobilism.org/search.php?sr=topics&sf=titleonly&keywords=test

This request works fine and returns the search results as it would in a web browser.

But then when generating a get or curl request, the page returned doesn't contain the results and asks to login (although the cookies are in the request).

I don't see what the difference is in between the insomnia request and the one with curl or wget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This request works fine and returns the search results as it would in
> a web browser.
>
> But then when generating a get or curl request, the page returned
> doesn't contain the results and asks to login (although the cookies
> are in the request).

Generally [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) request header is used by browser or other software to identify itself. [`wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) option for setting is

> `--user-agent=agent-string`
>
> Identify as agent-string to the HTTP server.(...)

Please try specifying same User-Agent as your browser is using and check if it would help.

Comment: I tried in the past with a user agent which didn't work, no idea why. This time I generated a curl command from the network tab of the devtools, removed everything except the cookie and the user-agent and it worked. Thanks !